# Fact constellation schema with 2 fact table

Tags: schema, data-warehouse, fact

I need your help about constellation schema, I want to analyze a crime dataset, but I should have at least two facts table… Can anyone give me some ideas how can I do it?
 PS: I already found a dataset 
 Thank you so much.

Comment: Why should you have at least two fact tables? What are your requirements?

Comment: Because I want to practice a constellation schema